# How active emmet on pugjs with vscode?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, pug, emmet

I wonder if someone knows how to active [emmet](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) toolkit with **pugjs** on **vscode**?

The toolkit is working good in an online editors like [codepen](https://codepen.io/), [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)

but it doesn't work on vscode and pugjs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [formatter-pug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexbabichev.formatter-pug) extension was behind this problem

when I disabled it emmet works as expected